# How to understand bazel coverage coverage.dat file?

Tags: go, bazel

Hello I have been searching the internet a lot but I cannot find an easy way to generate a html coverage file for our golang project but at least I can get a coverage.dat file which looks like this

```
mode: set
path/foo.go:13.58,15.2 1 1
path/foo.go:17.56,19.2 1 1
```

I couldn't even find the document for this file, what do these numbers mean? It looks like line number but not quite.

My Bazel version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like line number but not quite

fields are: `name.go:line.column,line.column numberOfStatements count`

[Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0104a31b8fbcbe52728a08867b26415d282c35d2/src/cmd/cover/profile.go#L56)

You can generate html with next command:

```
# Generate coverage profile using Cover tool
> go test -coverprofile=coverage.out ./.. 
# To analyze coverage via a browser
> go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

Last command will generate html file under `/tmp/coverXXXXX/coverage.html`

Comment: would you share more insights on what does that mean path/foo.go:13.58,15.2 1 1 does that mean from line 13 column 58 to line 15 column 2 the code is not covered by unit test?

Thanks for the go test opiton, but it is not convinient for me to use, our project is managed by bazel, go test will have errors saying path/foo.go is not found in $GOPATH or $GOROOT.

Comment: Last field 0/1 is flag signals statements are covered or not.